# OS X Keyboard Layout in Unity or Ubuntu

Tags: unity, keyboard, keyboard-layout, mac, macosx

I want to use ALL of the mac keyboard shortcuts for everything in Unity.

Example: Copy (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), Paste (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>), etc.

I have not found a way to do this where <kbd>CMD</kbd> is the modifier key instead of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, whilst <kbd>CTRL</kbd> still acts "normal" in terminal (say quitting a process with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible to change system shortcuts like  copy and paste (at least without recompiling most of the OS). It's also not possible to change application shortcuts like quit globally (though it is possible to change these one at a time). The only (easy) way to get the kind of behaviour you want is to write a pair of layouts (one that swaps Ctrl and Super/Cmd, one that unswaps them), then manually change layouts when you switch to the Terminal. If this is acceptable for you, I can show you how to do it (I'll probably write it out anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the offer @pconley, a write up for anyone who searches might be super useful - but this doesn't quite scale.

I did attempt this for a while with xmodmap, and a few other applications that sat on top of the window manager (or input manager in this case). It worked in *most* cases, but not all. It's kind of weird though that KDE actually has a layout like this, with the shortcuts set - but Unity or Gnome do not. Kind of saddens me. Maybe I'll go with KDE if this is one of my biggest annoyances/requirements with linux (always has been since I started using it many eons ago).

Answer (score -1):

Macintosh keyboard layouts are available on Ubuntu. Go to System Settings > Keyboard Layouts.

In this window, you can manage your keyboard layouts, i.e. you can add Macintosh layouts and set them by default. ;-)

Comment: Perhaps I'm dense, but I don't see that as mapping copy, paste, etc? Or do I need to restart compiz/unity?

Comment: No, you don't need to restart anything.

Comment: The Macintosh keyboards only add third- and fourth-level symbols; they don't alter Ctrl or Super.

Comment: @pconley Thank you. That's what I thought. So basically the functionality I am looking for isn't done with the keyboard layout (as I suspected in the first place).

Know of any other way?

Comment: Down-voting as this doesn't answer the question, as discussed in the comments.