# OS X keyboard mapping and shortcuts in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, shortcut-keys, macosx

I know there are similar questions:

- [OS X Keyboard Layout in Unity or Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162035/os-x-keyboard-layout-in-unity-or-ubuntu)
- [Mac Os keyboard layout in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56573/mac-os-keyboard-layout-in-ubuntu)

But they have no solution for that question.

How to setup OS X keyboard mapping and shortcuts in Ubuntu 12.10?

Actually, it means to support at least **Application and other OS X shortcuts** table from [OS X keyboard shortcuts](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343) on non-Mac keyboard.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @PratyushNalam See my edit

Comment: Do you mean stuff like volume control from the keyboard etc? Which model you have? I have mid 2012 and those keys work out of the box on 12.10

Comment: @PratyushNalam That keys are also appreciated. Oh, I didn't say that Ubuntu is not on the Mac. Examples of interested shortcuts: Cmd-W, Cmd-Q, Cmd-V, Cmd-C etc.

Comment: If it is not on the Mac, where is it? Then how will you have a Cmd key?

Comment: @PratyushNalam Standard PC keyboard with renamed keys: Windows-key into Option key and Alt key into Cmd key

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
sudo apt-get install pommed
```

I installed this on 12.04 but found it was unnecessary on 12.10. Anyways, see if this works for you.

Source: http://alioth.debian.org/projects/pommed/