# NEED OS X shortcuts / settings

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, asus, macosx, trackpad

## TLDR

I'm used to working with os x on apple computers. I need os x key bindings / keyboard shortcuts, two finger scrolling and the trackpad of this device to not respond to my hands resting on the keyboard... any mac users who have successfully made the switch to ubuntu without going insane, please help.

## LDR

I just installed ubuntu on an asus laptop and there are a few things driving me insane:

- The trackpad on this laptop is located where my hands normally rest... so while i'm typing in order to keep focus on the thing i'm typing i have to essentially hover above the keyboard. I need to fix this problem. How do? I don't even know how to phrase that in a way that makes googling the answer possibwle.
- I need the *alt* key on this computer to serve the function of the *command* key on a mac.
- I need os x key bindings. Thankfully the **alt + tab** command functions the same way as the app switcher on a mac but... i need to be able to hit *alt + spacebar* and have it launch the ubuntu equivalent of spotlight.
- I do not know how to scroll on this computer. There is no scroll thing on the trackpad. Is there a way to turn enable this trackpad to be a multi-finger recognizing trackpad?

I've tried:
[this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214531/os-x-keyboard-mapping-and-shortcuts-in-ubuntu-12-10)
and the posts he mentions. pommed is running but it doesn't seem like it's doing anything.

A lot of these problems I haven't been able to solve because I don't know the correct phrasing or terminology to get relevant search results in google or even here.I feel like there **has** to have been someone in the history of ubuntu who came from a mac environment and made ubuntu feel like os x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are used to OS X you can google 'Macbuntu' and find detailed instructions on how to change Ubuntu to look like OS X.
About the keyboard-shortcuts, the answer has been posted down below.
Next, gnome do serves as a good alternative for quicksilver.
indicator synapse is the Linux equivalent of spotlight.
Also there are some good touch pad drivers online with extended settings that recognize the palm of your hand and don't see it is an intended gesture.
Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

i assume you are using 13.10

for keyboard shortcuts you can go to `System settings > keyboard > shortcut` than change it with your desire.

for mouse got to `System settings > Mouse` then check `disable mouse typing` and check `two finger scrolling`

as changing `alt` key have you tried this [How do I switch the Command key and Control key on a MacBook Pro?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131900/how-do-i-switch-the-command-key-and-control-key-on-a-macbook-pro-12-04)  ?

Comment: i'd upvote your answer if i could but i dont have 15 rep yet. im back and forth between u and this.foo for who answered the question because u both answered different parts of it.